# Read multiple rows the same Content from excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have to read data from excel file and user can type sample data like this:

No

```
| student name| email| test subject 1| test subject 2|
1.     Adam.      Email.     5.                   6
                             9.                   7
                             10.                  4
2.     Nova.        Mail.    2.                   1
3.     Kevin.     Email.      5.                  9
                              3.                   2
```

As you can see data from excel file above, how can I import data above to database? How can I determined 1 record like data such as Adam has 3 rows , nova 1 rows (or more if user enter dynamic data)
Anyone can help me?

Comment: This might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447918/php-import-excel-into-database-xls-xlsx]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447918/php-import-excel-into-database-xls-xlsx

Comment: Also when you read in a record, store the name and email in a temporary variable. If the following record is missing a name or email use the value that you saved.

Comment: Thank You very mục